# Azure server not accepting rdp, stuck on Settings screen?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, rdp

I cannot currently rdp to my Azure server. After checking the RDP endpoints were open I looked at the Boot Diagnostics and a Settings window was displayed.

Is this significant, if so how do I correct it.

Note: I created another VM based on a previous image of the problematic server and the same thing happened.

[image]
Thanks
Phil

Comment: The image from azure or hyper-v?

Comment: I created the image in the Azure Classic portal as per the following instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-classic-capture-image

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I had test in my lab, follow this article I had  create image, and it works. Maybe there are some points need to consider:
 1.run sysprep.exe, in Shutdown Options, select Shutdown. After sysprep.exe was running, we will disconnect this VM, but it does not mean this VM was **stopped**.
We should confirm the status of this VM, we can via portal to check the status:
[image]
2.After this VM's status is stopped, then we can click the VM and select the virtual machine you want to capture.
[image]

3.Then we can use this image to create a new VM.

You should re-capture this image.

Note:Prior to caputuring an image of an Azure virtual machine, it is recommended the target virtual machine be **backed up**

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My main question was why I could not rdp to the original server and if the the screen displayed in the Azure Boot Diagnostics was significant. I re-created the vm from the image as an extra test and replicated the problem so I don't think the imaging process is a factor in this problem.Regards Phil.

Comment: @philp  Sysprep.exe will generalize the operating system, so you could not rdp to the original server.

Comment: @philp  Sysprep removes all your personal account information, among other things, and prepares the machine to be used as an image. For details about sysprep, refer to the link. https://technet.microsoft.com/library/bb457073.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @philp Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.